# Why does Solaris 11 install desktop packages when I just want subversion?

Tags: software-installation, solaris

I want to install subversion (developer/versioning/subversion) in my Solaris 11 global zone. When I run

```
pkg install developer/versioning/subversion
```

Solaris wants to install 35 packages totalling 677 MB! Why is this? Is there any way to specify to 'pkg' to ignore dependencies? subversion itself is only around 7 MB.

For example:

```
           Packages to install:        35
            Services to change:         6
     Estimated space available:   3.47 GB 
Estimated space to be consumed: 677.84 MB
       Create boot environment:        No 
Create backup boot environment:        No
          Rebuild boot archive:        No

Changed packages: solaris   codec/flac
    None -> 1.2.1,5.11-0.175.2.0.0.39.0:20140512T125954Z   
codec/libtheora
    None -> 1.1.1,5.11-0.175.2.0.0.24.0:20131001T134246Z   
codec/ogg-vorbis
    None -> 2.30.0,5.11-0.175.2.0.0.39.0:20140512T130005Z   
codec/speex
    None -> 1.2,5.11-0.175.2.0.0.27.0:20131111T145932Z   
developer/versioning/subversion
    None -> 1.7.5,5.11-0.175.2.0.0.42.1:20140623T013003Z   
gnome/gnome-audio
    None -> 2.30.0,5.11-0.175.2.0.0.27.0:20131111T150212Z

<snip>

  web/browser/firefox
    None -> 17.0.11,5.11-0.175.2.0.0.41.0:20140609T232336Z

Services:   restart_fmri:
    svc:/application/desktop-cache/desktop-mime-cache:default
    svc:/application/desktop-cache/gconf-cache:default
    svc:/application/desktop-cache/mime-types-cache:default
    svc:/application/font/fc-cache:default
    svc:/application/texinfo-update:default
    svc:/system/manifest-import:default
```

Comment: Welcome to the package dependency hell.

Comment: I wonder what it is that pulls _firefox_ in? [The manifest](http://pkg.oracle.com/solaris/release/manifest/0/developer%2Fversioning%2Fsubversion@1.9.5%2C5.12-5.12.0.0.0.122.0%3A20170510T184651Z) doesn't look too heavy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Oracle Bug 15774570](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/BugDisplay?id=15774570), this is because subversion relies on `libproxy` for making connections via proxies, and by default, that brings in `libproxy-mozjs` for parsing pac files with proxy definitions written in JavaScript.  Since Solaris 11.3 and older don't have a standalone mozjs package, that brings in Firefox to use the bundled mozjs library.

This has been fixed for Solaris 11.4, and for older releases, you should be able to avoid it either by running `pkg avoid libproxy-mozjs` before the install, or doing the install with `pkg install --reject libproxy-mozjs subversion`.

Answer (score 1):

Not that I'm aware of.  Agreed on it being odd that so many dependencies are pulled in for subversion, which appears to be caused by those dependencies having other dependencies and so forth.

However, with the latest version of subversion being and older 1.7.20 in the support repo, you may be better of getting the latest version (1.9.7) from Apache and building it yourself depending on what your needs are.

You could also enable compression on the ZFS filesystem.  Currently it can only be set to on for the root fs, but they may allow greater compression algorithms in the future based on RFE bugids.  Granted, not a solution, but it may help give you some extra breathing room.